# Setting Constant Buffer Directx

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

So, I'm trying to get my constant buffer in my shader to have a projection matrix that is orthogonal...

Can anyone tell me why I'm rendering nothing now that I tried to do this?

I assumed I needed to make two mapped subresources, and two buffers, one for vertex and the other for constant, maybe this is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
    Vertex OurVertices[] =
{
    { D3DXVECTOR2(-0.5f,-0.5f), D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) },
    { D3DXVECTOR2(-0.5f,0.5f), D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) },
    { D3DXVECTOR2(0.5f,0.5f), D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) },
    { D3DXVECTOR2(-0.5f,-0.5f), D3DXCOLOR(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) },
    { D3DXVECTOR2(0.5f,0.5f), D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) },
    { D3DXVECTOR2(0.5f,-0.5f), D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) }
};


// create the vertex buffer
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc;
ZeroMemory(&vertexBufferDesc, sizeof(vertexBufferDesc));

vertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;                // write access access by CPU and GPU
vertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex) * 6;             // size is the VERTEX struct * 3
vertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;       // use as a vertex buffer
vertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;    // allow CPU to write in buffer
dev->CreateBuffer(&vertexBufferDesc, NULL, &pVBuffer);       // create the buffer
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ms_Vertex;
devcon->Map(pVBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &ms_Vertex);   
memcpy(ms_Vertex.pData, OurVertices, sizeof(OurVertices));                 // copy the data
devcon->Unmap(pVBuffer, NULL);                                      // unmap the buffer
devcon->VSSetConstantBuffers(NULL, 1, &pVBuffer);       // Finanly set the constant buffer in the vertex shader with the updated values.


MatrixBufferType* dataPtr;
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC constantBufferDesc;   // create the constant buffer

ZeroMemory(&constantBufferDesc, sizeof(constantBufferDesc));

constantBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
constantBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
constantBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(MatrixBufferType);
constantBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
constantBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
constantBufferDesc.StructureByteStride = 0;
dev->CreateBuffer(&constantBufferDesc, NULL, &pCBuffer);       // create the buffer

D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ms_CBuffer;
devcon->Map(pCBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &ms_CBuffer);
D3DXMatrixOrthoLH(&m_orthoMatrix, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, 1);
D3DXMatrixTranspose(&m_orthoMatrix, &m_orthoMatrix);
dataPtr = (MatrixBufferType*)ms_CBuffer.pData;
dataPtr->projection = m_orthoMatrix;
memcpy(ms_CBuffer.pData, &dataPtr, sizeof(MatrixBufferType));
devcon->Unmap(pCBuffer, NULL);
devcon->VSSetConstantBuffers(NULL, 1, &pCBuffer);       // Finally set the constant buffer in the vertex shader with the updated values.
```

So, attempting to put my projection matrix to use in my shader code:

```
cbuffer ConstantBuffer
{
matrix world;
matrix view;
matrix projection;
};

VOut VShader(float4 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR)
{
VOut output;

output.position = position;
output.position = mul(output.position, projection);
output.color = color;

return output;
}
```

Causes my quad which was originally rendering, to disappear.

This leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong, I just don't know what yet.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your shader? You should look at the output of vertex shader

Comment: I'm really not sure how to do that, my shader file is something I created, .shader, and visual studio can't seem to reach it to debug?

Comment: This link can help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125501.aspx

Comment: You can't debug your shaders like you do with your C++ code. You will have to capture a frame. The above link should help you or Google for more information.

Comment: Can you comment at all on how I'm setting my constants for the shader?

Comment: Open your .exe in RenderDoc, capture a screen and look at the content of the pixel fragments passed to the Pixel Shader.

Comment: And of course also look at the constant buffer you bound to the Vertex Shader to check if the projection matrix is ok.

Comment: This should draw a much larger quad `D3DXMatrixOrthoOffCenterLH(&m_orthoMatrix, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);` in your current setup useful while debugging.

Comment: Hi All, I was able to figure this out.

https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/698463-beginning-directx-ortho/?do=findComment&comment=5388481